# Can you identify these column decorators?

Tags: part-identification

I want to decorate some columns with these little round ionic scroll-looking things. Does anyone know the part number?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Scroll with Hollow Stud

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=20310&idColor=2